# A schedule where everyone will have two days off of four days total and still get to work with everyone

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

There's a total of 8 people. Everyone will have 2 days of every week. There's only 4 available days every week. There needs to be 4 people at work on every single day.
How can i structure it so that everyone gets to work with everyone exactly as many times, and how many weeks does this schedule need to be?

Comment: It only takes one week. On the first week, everyone comes to work together on Monday, so they all meet on that Monday. If this is not a satisfactory answer, you should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4281426/edit) your question to clarify.

Comment: Is there a minimum or maximum number of people that work on any single day?

Comment: Should be even out, so i guess 4 is the maximum and minimum!